# Java: Better way to convert Double object to float

Tags: java, casting

Suppose I'm given a Double object d and a function that takes in a primitive float, is there a better way to pass on object do to the function than by double casting?

```
Double fakePi = 3.14  
void function(float num) {}
```

`function(fakePi)`: Returns a compiling error as function does not take Double object as argument

`function((float) fakePi)`: Returns a compiling error as Double cannot be converted to a float

`function((float) (double) fakePi)`: 
Compiles and runs without error

Although this works, my instincts tells me that there are better ways to do this and that I should avoid doing multiple type castings, especially since float, double, Double are closely related to each other.

Comment: Try `fakePi.floatValue()`. Always consult the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#floatValue()) when in doubt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Double class has a floatValue() property.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html

```
function(fakePi.floatValue());
```